# Bash Launch command when time between 04:00-05:00

Tags: bash

As in subject, I want make bash script that will check the time, and when it is between 04:00-05:00 in night, it will execute one command.

Can someone help me?

Comment: check `cron` and `at` manpages

Answer (score 1):

The best way to schedule an event is using `crontab`.

For example, below `crontab` syntax will schedule to  execute your script `foo.sh` at 04:00 AM daily.

```
0 4 * * * /bin/foo.sh
```